# How to hide and show button i have tried it hide but not show second button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to hide and show button i have tried it hide but not show second button

```
function mybutton1() {
    document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
}

function mybutton2() {
    document.getElementById('<%=Button2.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Show html of your buttons ?

Answer (score -1):

you want to do like this

```js
function mybutton1() {
  document.getElementById('Button1').style.display = "none";
}

function mybutton2() {
  document.getElementById('Button1').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" name="button1" value="button1" id="Button1" onclick="mybutton1();">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" name="button2" value="button2" id="Button2" onclick="mybutton2();">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This won't work, web forms will prefix the button ids and the javascript won't find them.

Comment: @kmcoulson i have done that thing because stack overflow editor will not work with asp.net syntax. please think before downvoting

Comment: not sure what you mean? The code above won't work because the ids won't match?

Comment: if you can't understood thing then why are you downvoting the answer

Comment: @kmcoulson stack over flow provide code editor in which you can run script, html and css. you can not run asp.net syntax in that editor. now i think you can understand what i mean. i just showing him that how to achieve this goal